# C++ HTTP Client recv() and write file problem

Tags: c++, http, websocket, httprequest

I wrote the HTTP client with c ++ to download files in the background, and it works diligently, but it gets corrupted when I download pdf which is not normally corrupted.

There are libraries like libcurl poco for this.But since I wanted to see the basics, I wrote pure socket code.I looked at the source code of the libraries(like curl), but I didn't understand anything from them.

file.pdf address : https://www.axmag.com/download/pdfurl-guide.pdf

This is my code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <WS2tcpip.h>
#pragma comment(lib,"ws2_32.lib")
using namespace std;
void main()
{
setlocale(LC_ALL,
    "Turkish");




WSADATA wsdata;
WORD ver = MAKEWORD(2, 2);


int ws0k = WSAStartup(ver, &wsdata);

if (ws0k != 0) {
    return;
}// classic startup operations


SOCKET client = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

if (client == INVALID_SOCKET) {
    return;
}
else {
    cout << "Soket oluşturuldu." << endl; // successfully created socket
}



struct hostent* host;
host = gethostbyname("www.axmag.com");


sockaddr_in target;
target.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = *((unsigned long*)host->h_addr); //WEBSITE ADDRESS
target.sin_port = htons(80); // HTTP PORT : 80
target.sin_family = AF_INET; // I don't know the address family of http.

int conn = connect(client, (sockaddr*)&target, sizeof(target));

if (conn < 0) {
    return;
}
else {
    cout << "Bağlantı isteği başarılı." << endl; // successfully connected.
}


char HTTP_MESSAGE[] = "GET /download/pdfurl-guide.pdf HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: www.axmag.com\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n";


if (send(client, HTTP_MESSAGE, sizeof(HTTP_MESSAGE), 0) < 0) { // send http request.
    return;
}
else {
    cout << "Komut başarıyla gönderildi." << endl; // Successfully send http request.
}


FILE* file = NULL; // file

file = fopen("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\test.pdf", "wb"); //Create file

if (file == NULL) {
    return;
}
else {
    cout << "Dosya oluşturuldu." << endl; //Successfully created file.
}

char recvbuf[1024];


int received;
while (received = recv(client, recvbuf, sizeof(recvbuf), 0) > 0) { // RECV
    cout << recvbuf << endl;
    fwrite(recvbuf, 1, received, file); // write data to file

}



fclose(file);
closesocket(client);
WSACleanup();

system("pause");
}
```

I download it successfully. The problem was with fwrite function.
I changed the ElementSize parameter to the value of the buffer and it happened.

Solution code :

```
char recvbuf[64];

int received;

while (received = recv(client, recvbuf, sizeof(recvbuf), 0) > 0) { // RECV
    cout << recvbuf << endl;
    fwrite(recvbuf, 64, received, file); // write data to file
}
```

Comment: I would suggest looking at the raw response with something like `curl -iv --raw`. You need to parse or otherwise handle the HTTP response, which could even be using chunked transfer encoding. The server doesn't just send the raw bytes of the file.

Comment: shouldn't you have a `fwrite` inside your `while` loop? You'll also need to trim off the http response headers before writing

Comment: I received the size of the file in bytes. (98 Kilobytes) And I changed the buffer to 100,000 bytes.(File size) I put the fwrite function into the loop, but the pdf is still broken.

Comment: Tour solution with the 64 cannot possibly work. You are writing 64x more data than you received. It will quite possibly SIGSEGV. NB The PDF is going to contain all the HTTP headers, as you've made no attempt to remove them, or to handle any possible content-encoding or multiparts either.

Answer (score 1):

Once problem is that operator precedence for `>` is higher than for `=`, so your `received` variable will get either `0` or `1`. You can use an extra set of parentheses to fix that:

```
while ((received = recv(client, recvbuf, sizeof(recvbuf), 0)) > 0) {
...
```

When the Web server sends back its response, the response will include an HTTP response header. You need to read this response header and leave it out of the file.

Simplistically,

```
// Skip the HTTP header
std::string http_resp;
auto eoh = std::string::npos;
while ((received = recv(client, recvbuf, sizeof(recvbuf), 0)) > 0) {
    http_resp.append(recvbuf, received);
    auto eoh = http_resp.find("\r\n\r\n");
    if (eoh != std::string::npos) {
        if ((eoh + 4) < http_resp.size()) {
            auto rest = http_resp.substr(eoh + 4);
            fwrite(rest.c_str(), 1, rest.size(), file);
        }
        break;
    }
}

// Get the rest of the file
if (received > 0) {
    while ((received = recv(client, recvbuf, sizeof(recvbuf), 0)) > 0) {
        fwrite(recvbuf, 1 ,received, file);
    }
}
```

Comment: When I changed the Fwrite element size, I succeeded in a way that I did not understand.I wrote the solution on top. But thank you very much.

Comment: @user207421: I `break` after finding the end of headers.

Answer (score -1):

Your program receives up to 1024 bytes at a time. Each time this loop runs:

```
while (received = recv(client, recvbuf, sizeof(recvbuf), 0) > 0) { // RECV
    cout << "Veriler alınıyor.." << endl;
}
```

your program calls `recv` and receives up to 1024 bytes.

Once no more data is left, then your program writes the last chunk of data.

You need to write *all* the chunks of data, by calling `fwrite` *in* the loop.

Comment: I received the size of the file in bytes. (98 Kilobytes)
And I changed the buffer to 100,000 bytes.(File size)
I put the fwrite function into the loop, but the pdf is still broken.